# Converting date format m.Y into MySQL compatible Y-m-d in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have date string like:

`08.2015`

What I want to do is, to convert it into MySQL compatible date format:

`date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date_create_from_format('m.Y', "08.2015")));`

Doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

BTW: It's okay if I'll get `2015-06-01` result.

Comment: 08.2015 where is the date in this string? 08 is month?

Comment: @TarunUpadhyay 08 - month,

Comment: What out put do you want to get with 
 
08.2015? Is it 2015-08?

Comment: from 08.2015 to get  2015-08-01

Answer (score 2):

You don't need strtotime there.

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('m.Y', "08.2015")->format("Y-m-d");
```

**Output**: `2015-08-31`

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/409391)**

And if you always want to get first date of month with only `m.Y` given, you can do

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', "01."."08.2015")->format("Y-m-d");
```

**Output**: `2015-08-01`

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/409393)**

Comment: Note that I have kept `"01"` separate from the rest of the string just to indicate that its a new addition. Otherwise even `"01.$mY"` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//explode the date
$dateProps = explode('.',"08.2015");

//prepare the format
$date = $dateProps[1].'-'.$dateProps[0].'-01';

//use date functions
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, but I think there is one line version of what you wrote

Comment: Yeah in case if your month is not appended zero then the second line is required

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$var = '08.2015';
$date = '01-'.str_replace('.', '-', $var);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below SQL useful to you.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('06.2015','%m.%Y'),'%Y-%m');
```

output: `2015-06`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use `strtotime` , it should be this : `strtotime('01.08.2015')`, that is to say , Year month day must be all needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below sql-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('08.2015','%m.%Y'),'%Y-%m-01')
```